# how apt-get "knows" about globbing (*, asterisk char) ? Why shell doesn't convert it to filenames?

Tags: shell

If I write

```
$ apt-get install php*
```

then apt "knows" I want php + php-module-a + php-module-z ;  how it receives the asterisk sign, when otherwise it is consumed by the shell?

else, is there a shell voodoo?

fi

2. How can I recognize asterisk char argument with my own CLI program, **without** escaping it?

Comment: It is not consumed by the shell. If it doesn't match any files, the shell leaves it verbatim, and apt-get expands it to appropriate package names.

Comment: Also, affected by `nullglob` and `failglob` shell options.

Comment: @Berry Tsakala : It is the voodoo of the invoker: If you call it as `apt-get install 'php*'`, you pass the asterisk literally and the shell won't touch it.

Comment: but i'm not using any quotes!   `apt install php*`